# Are there Stirling numbers of $z$-kind?

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, summation, stirling-numbers, derivation-of-formulae

In my post [The formula for $g\frac{d}{dg}g\frac{d}{dg}...g\frac{d}{dg}f(g)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4481421/the-formula-for-g-fracddgg-fracddg-g-fracddgfg) I found a formula given by a finite sum with Sitrling numbers of the second kind.  $$ \sum_{j=1}^{n}{n \brace j}g^{j}\frac{d^{j}}{dg^{j}}f(g) = g\frac{d}{dg}g\frac{d}{dg}...g\frac{d}{dg}f(g)$$

Stirling numbers of the second kind are given by $$ {n + 1\brace j} = j{n \brace j} + {n \brace j - 1}. $$

Now, consider $g^{2}\frac{d}{dg}g^{2}\frac{d}{dg}...g^{2}\frac{d}{dg}f(g)$. First of all, it appears to be given by $$ \sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{j}g^{j+n}\frac{d^{j}}{dg^{j}}f(g). $$

Now, redefine the Stirling numbers to be
$$ {n + 1\brace j} = (j+n){n \brace j} + {n \brace j - 1}. $$
Then notice that I can conduct only a slightly different proof by induction to the one I linked. Generally, to obtain a formula for $g^{z}\frac{d}{dg}g^{z}\frac{d}{dg}...g^{z}\frac{d}{dg}f(g)$ one needs to introduce numbers of the form $$ {n + 1\brace j} = (j+(z-1)n){n \brace j} + {n \brace j - 1}. $$

Are there Stirling numbers of $z$-kind?

Comment: Google for *Stirling numbers of the third kind* and *Stirling numbers of the fourth kind*. There are a few recent papers.

Comment: Not quite, but the $r-$Whitney numbers of the second kind are very similar. See for example the introduction in https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v25i1p48/pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered that the z-Stirling numbers, as I called them, do occur in the generating series for a family of functions.

Let ${n\brace j}_z$ be the z-Stirling numbers from the question. Then

$$ \sum_{n=j}^{\infty}{n \brace j}_{q}\frac{x^n}{n!}=\frac{(f(x)-1)^j}{j!}, $$
where $$ f^q = \frac{d}{dx}f $$
and $$ f(0)=1. $$