# The ultimate polylogarithm ladder

Tags: summation, riemann-zeta, polylogarithm, derivation-of-formulae

As you can see, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4741077/verification-of-the-generalized-polylogarithm-formula) I performed a derivation of a quite simple formula, not much differing from the standard integral representation of the Polylogarithm. Seeking to make it fancier, I arrived at [generalized Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4497108/are-there-stirling-numbers-of-z-kind) and once again [applied the result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4772982/polylogarithm-further-generalized).

However, the resulting integral is still not simple. This kept me experimenting and in order to simplify the integral, I discovered the following.

Suppose $f(g(z))=g'(z)$. Then
$$ (f(z)\frac{d}{dz})^n u(z) = \sum_{j=0}^{n} <n, j> u^{(j)}(z) $$
where $$ \forall j \in \mathbb{N} | \sum_{n=j}^{\infty}<n, j>\frac{x^n}{n!} = \frac{(g(x)-g(0))^j}{j!} $$ and $z$ is evaluated at $g(0)$. When $f(z)=z$, this yields the already known exponential generating series with Stirling numbers of the second kind, whereas taking $f=exp$ yields a sum with Stirling numbers of the first kind.

Replacing the Stirling numbers with $<n, j>$ in the original derivation will lead one to conclude that $$\frac{d^{s-1}}{dy^{s-1}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} y^{n+s-1} (f(z)\frac{d}{dz})^n Li_{s+n}(z) = z\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{s-1}\frac{1}{\frac{e^t}{g(t)}-1}dt, $$ where $z=g(0)$ and $y=1$. You will notice that in the original derivation I use $x$ in $g$, but the $x$ cancels out on both sides eventually. Also, the $z^j$ factor from the derivation is absent.

Taking $g(z)=\frac{e^z}{e^z+1}$ gives $$ \frac{d^{s-1}}{dy^{s-1}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} y^{n+s-1} ((z-z^2)\frac{d}{dz})^n Li_{s+n}(z) = \frac{\Gamma(s)}{2}.$$

Do you think this qualifies as advanced enough to be considered research? I am an undergraduate student of computing science. Do you have any ideas on what Riemann Zeta function identities could be derived from this?