# Verification of the generalized polylogarithm formula

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, riemann-zeta, polylogarithm, derivation-of-formulae

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4693037/generalized-formula-for-the-polylogarithm) I posted a generalized formula for the polylogarithm I had discovered. However, for $x=\frac{1}{2}$, $z=\frac{1}{2}$, $p=1$ wolfram alpha yields a result different than what the double integral is supposed to be equal to. Where is the mistake?

$$ Li_s(z) = \frac{z}{(s- 1)!}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{s-1}}{e^t-z}dt. $$

$$ (z\frac{d}{dz})^n Li_s(z) = Li_{s-n}(z). $$

$$ (z\frac{d}{dz})^n Li_s(z) = \sum_{j=0}^n {n \brace j}z^j \frac{d^j}{dz^j}Li_s z$$by the formula from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4481421/the-formula-for-g-fracddgg-fracddg-g-fracddgfg). $$ = \sum_{j=0}^n {n \brace j}z^j \frac{d^j}{dz^j}\frac{z}{(s-1)!}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{s-1}}{e^t-z}dt$$ $$ = \sum_{j=0}^n {n \brace j}z^{j}\frac{1}{(s-1)!}(z\frac{d^j}{dz^j} \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{s-1}}{e^t-z}dt+j\frac{d^{j-1}}{dz^{j-1}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{s-1}}{e^t-z}dt)$$ $$ = \sum_{j=0}^n {n \brace j}z^{j}\frac{1}{(s-1)!}(z j! \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{s-1}}{(e^t-z)^{j+1}}dt+j(j-1)!\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{s-1}}{(e^t-z)^j}dt).$$

Take $$s(n)=c+n.$$

$$ Li_c(z) = \sum_{j=0}^n {n \brace j}z^{j}\frac{1}{(c+n-1)!}(z j! \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{c+n-1}}{(e^t-z)^{j+1}}dt+j(j-1)!\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{c+n-1}}{(e^t-z)^j}dt)$$

$$ x^{n+c-1}Li_c(z) = \sum_{j=0}^n {n \brace j}z^{j}\frac{x^{n+c-1}}{(c+n-1)!}(z j! \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{c+n-1}}{(e^t-z)^{j+1}}dt+j(j-1)!\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{c+n-1}}{(e^t-z)^j}dt)$$
$$ \frac{d^{c-1}}{dx^{c-1}}x^{n+c-1}Li_c(z) = \sum_{j=0}^n {n \brace j}z^{j}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}(z j! \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{c+n-1}}{(e^t-z)^{j+1}}dt+j(j-1)!\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{c+n-1}}{(e^t-z)^j}dt)$$
$$ \frac{d^{c-1}}{dx^{c-1}}\frac{x^{c-1}}{1-x}Li_c(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^n {n \brace j}z^{j}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}(z j! \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{c+n-1}}{(e^t-z)^{j+1}}dt+j(j-1)!\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{c+n-1}}{(e^t-z)^j}dt)$$
$$ \frac{d^{c-1}}{dx^{c-1}}\frac{x^{c-1}}{1-x}Li_c(z) = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=j}^{\infty} {n \brace j}z^{j}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}(z j! \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{c+n-1}}{(e^t-z)^{j+1}}dt+j(j-1)!\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{c+n-1}}{(e^t-z)^j}dt)$$
$$ \frac{d^{c-1}}{dx^{c-1}}\frac{x^{c-1}}{1-x}Li_c(z) = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} z^{j}(z j! \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{c-1}}{(e^t-z)^{j+1}}\frac{(e^{tx}-1)^j}{j!}dt+j(j-1)!\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{c-1}}{(e^t-z)^j}\frac{(e^{tx}-1)^j}{j!}dt)$$
by $ \sum_{n=j}^{\infty}{n \brace j}\frac{x^n}{n!}=\frac{(e^x-1)^j}{j!}. $

Introduce the Gamma function: $j!=\int_0^{\infty}h^je^{-h}dh$
$$ \frac{d^{c-1}}{dx^{c-1}}\frac{x^{c-1}}{1-x}Li_c(z) = \int_0^{\infty}(\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} z^{j}(z h^j \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{c-1}}{(e^t-z)^{j+1}}\frac{(e^{tx}-1)^j}{j!}dt+jh^{j-1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{c-1}}{(e^t-z)^j}\frac{(e^{tx}-1)^j}{j!}dt))e^{-h}dh$$

$$ \frac{d^{c-1}}{dx^{c-1}}\frac{x^{c-1}}{1-x}Li_c(z) = $$
$$=\int_0^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}z^{j+1}h^je^{-h}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{(e^{tx}-1)^j}{j!}\frac{t^{c-1}}{(e^t-z)^{j+1}}dtdh$$
$$-\int_0^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}z^{j}h^{j-1}e^{-h}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{(e^{tx}-1)^j}{j!}\frac{t^{c-1}}{(e^t-z)^{j}}dtdh$$
$$+\frac{d}{dv}\int_0^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}v^{j+1}h^{j-1}e^{-h}\int_o^{\infty}\frac{(e^{tx}-1)^j}{j!}\frac{t^{c-1}}{(e^t-z)^{j}}dtdh$$
where the derivative w.r.t. $v$ is evaluated at $z$.

$$ \frac{d^{c-1}}{dx^{c-1}}\frac{x^{c-1}}{1-x}Li_c(z) = $$
$$\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}t^{c-1}\frac{z}{e^t-z}e^{\frac{e^{tx}-1}{e^t-z}zh-h}dtdh$$
$$-\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}t^{c-1}\frac{1}{h}e^{\frac{e^{tx}-1}{e^t-z}zh-h}dtdh$$
$$+\frac{d}{dv}\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}t^{c-1}\frac{v}{h}e^{\frac{e^{tx}-1}{e^t-z}vh-h}dtdh$$

So in the end,

$$ \frac{d^{c-1}}{dx^{c-1}}\frac{x^{c-1}}{1-x}Li_c(z) = \int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}t^{c-1}(\frac{z}{e^t-z}+\frac{e^{tx}-1}{e^t-z})e^{\frac{e^{tx}-1}{e^t-z}zh-h}dtdh.$$

If this was true, one could get the closed form of Apery's constant. This is because picking $z=\frac{1}{2}, x=\frac{1}{2}$ yields the Gamma function, and the Trilogarithm at $z=\frac{1}{2}$ is known.

Where did I go wrong? As far as I know, it could be convergence issues by introducing the Gamma function. Only that introduction allows for swapping the two nested sums. However, the integral is still convergent. Moreover, this formula works for $x=0$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your notation, does $\left(z\frac{d}{dz}\right)^n\, \text{Li}_s(z)=z^n\, \frac{\partial^n\,\text{Li}_s(z)}{\partial z^n}$? If so, then $z^n\, \frac{\partial^n\,\text{Li}_s(z)}{\partial z^n}=\text{Li}_{s-n}(z)$ is true for $n\in\{0 ,1\}$ but is not more generally true. For example $z^2\, \frac{\partial^2\text{Li}_s(z)}{\partial z^2}=\text{Li}_{s-2}(z)-\text{Li}_{s-1}(z)$.

Comment: More generally, I believe one has $$z^n\, \frac{\partial^n\, \text{Li}_s(z)}{\partial z^n}=\sum\limits_{m=0}^n S_n^{(m)}\ \text{Li}_{s-m}(z),\quad n\in\mathbb{Z}\land n\geq 0$$ where $S_n^{(m)}$ is the [signed Stirling number of the first kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheFirstKind.html).

Comment: @stevenclark Thanks for interest in this topic. I discovered the formula for the repeated application of $x\frac{d}{dx}$ here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4481421/the-formula-for-g-fracddgg-fracddg-g-fracddgfg It does not mean $x^n\frac{d^n}{dx^n}$. Sorry for answering late.

Comment: I agree your final formula is wrong even for $c=1$.

Comment: @GEdgar It's not wrong if $x=0$.

Comment: @GEdgar If you have any insights into this formula whatsoever, please let me know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a slight error towards the end of your derivation.

Your final result should be

$$\frac{\partial^{c-1}}{\partial x^{c-1}}\frac{x^{c-1}}{1-x}\, \text{Li}_c(z)=\int_0^{\infty} \left(\int_0^{\infty} t^{c-1} \left(\frac{z}{e^t-z}+\frac{z\, \left(e^{t x}-1\right)}{e^t-z}\right) e^{\frac{e^{t x}-1}{e^t-z} z h-h} \, dt\right) \, dh\tag{1a}$$ $$=\int_0^{\infty} \left(\int_0^{\infty} t^{c-1}\, \frac{z\, e^{t x}}{e^t-z}\, e^{\frac{e^{t x}-1}{e^t-z} z h-h} \, dt\right) \, dh\tag{1b}$$

which can be rearranged as

$$\frac{\partial^{c-1}}{\partial x^{c-1}}\frac{x^{c-1}}{1-x}\, \text{Li}_c(z)=\int_0^{\infty} \left(\int_0^{\infty } e^{\frac{e^{t x}-1}{e^t-z} z h-h} \, dh\right) \frac{z\, e^{t x}}{e^t-z}\, t^{c-1}\, dt\tag{2a}$$ $$=\int_0^{\infty} \left(\frac{e^t-z}{e^t-z e^{t x}}\right) \frac{z\, e^{t x}}{e^t-z}\, t^{c-1}\, dt\tag{2b}$$ $$=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{z}{e^{t\, (1-x)}-z}\, t^{c-1}\, dt\tag{2c}$$

where the Mellin transform defined in formulas (2b) and (2c) above is valid for $\Re\left(\frac{z\, \left(e^{t x}-1\right)}{z-e^t}\right)>-1$.

---

For $c=3$ and $z=x=\frac{1}{2}$, formula (2c) above evaluates to the Mellin transform

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\left(e^{t\, \left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)}-\frac{1}{2}\right)}\,t^{3-1} \, dt=\frac{2}{3} \left(21\, \zeta (3)+4 \log ^3(2)-\pi ^2 \log (4)\right)\tag{3}$$

which is equivalent to

$$\frac{\partial^{3-1}}{\partial x^{3-1}}\frac{x^{3-1}}{1-x} \text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) =\frac{-21 \zeta (3)-4 \log ^3(2)+\pi ^2 \log (4)}{12 (x-1)^3}\tag{4}$$

evaluated at $x=\frac{1}{2}$.

---

More generally for $x=\frac{1}{2}$ one has

$$\int\limits_0^{\infty} \frac{z}{e^{\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right) t}-z}\, t^{c-1} \, dt=2^c\, \Gamma(c)\, \text{Li}_c(z)\,,\quad\Re(c)>0\tag{5}$$

and for $x=0$ one has

$$\int\limits_0^{\infty} \frac{z}{e^t-z}\, t^{c-1} \, dt=\Gamma(c)\, \text{Li}_c(z)\,,\quad\Re(c)>0\tag{6}$$

which is equivalent to the integral representation

$$\text{Li}_c(z)=\frac{z}{\Gamma(c)} \int\limits_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{e^t-z}\, t^{c-1} \, dt\,,\quad\Re(c)>0\tag{7}$$

referred to the beginning of the question above.